# SQL query- Update if exists, insert otherwise

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write an SQL query for MySQL so that a row is updated if it exists, but inserted if it does not.

i.e.

If row exists...

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
```

If it does not exist...

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Can this be done in one query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i believe you need to reverse your logic in order for it to work:

insert into a table - if it exists (same key) then update it.

this can be achieved by the `ON DUPLICATE` statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column=column+1
```

check the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Very clever. Just what I was after. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome.  While this post is old it is super helpful.  You rock.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

(For searching purposes, btw, this is usually referred to as an "upsert")