# How did this SQL duplicate row happen?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I had a flash game; a user had many items; each item is a row in a table in the database with columns:

```
id - user_id - item_type_id - quantity
```

Each time the user gets an item, I perform a select on the database to check if the user already has a row of that item type.  If it does not exist, then it is inserted, else increment the quantity and commit; everything always in a transaction.

Sometimes, when the game gets heavy traffic, duplicate item rows appear. Right now, I perform a select to check for duplicate rows to merge the quantities and delete the dupped row.

- How does this problem happen?
- How can I prevent the problem happening?

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that there is a unique constraint (index) on the column pair `user_id` and `item_type_id`.  Otherwise, the system can allow duplicate entries, exactly as you found out.

Comment: Thanks you for unique constraint on the column pair, I never know unique column pair used for this

Answer (score 1):

To avoid gettintg an error if trying to insert when updating was necessary, you can use ON DUPLICATE clause. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296946/sql-query-update-if-exists-insert-otherwise) link on how to use it.